# Browser Navigation Timing Level 2 timestamps are sometimes out of order

Tags: firefox, browser, safari, navigation-timing-api, boomerang

We are instrumenting pages with [Boomerang](https://github.com/akamai/boomerang), including much of the timeline data from [Navigation Timing Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/).  Most of the time this all works fine, but for a small percentage of the requests we are instrumenting, we get timestamps that seem out-of-order, leading to negative duration values when we subtract the out-of-order timestamps.

For example, looking at a few hours of our data, out of about 10M hits, I see:

- 56 instances where the timestamp for `responseEnd` is earlier than `responseStart` (e.g. `responseEnd` = 1619456473999, `responseStart` = 1619456479419)
- 17 instances where the timestamp for `unloadEventEnd` is earlier than `unloadEventStart` (e.g. `unloadEventEnd` = 1619457675970, `unloadEventStart` = 1619457682839)
- 7 instances where the timestamp for `domComplete` is earlier than `domLoading` (e.g. `domComplete` = 1619399859821, `domLoading` = 1619399860472)

I'm seeing this in a wide variety of browsers, many of which are old but some of which are newer (Firefox 88, Safari 13.1.2).

Basically I'm trying to figure out if this is something that happens to everybody and is just the state of the world with Nav Timing in real browsers (in which case I should just ignore it), or if it is more likely to be something wrong in our instrumentation (in which case I'll need to figure out what it is and fix it).

Thanks for any advice or feedback on your own experience!

----Scott.

Comment: Note that this is similar to [Navigation Timing API events not firing in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877131/), except that question was asked 6 years ago, when the answer "this is a pretty new feature it probably doesn't work yet" made sense; it no longer does.

Comment: Better to ask this question on the boomerang github page. We very rarely check Stack Overflow. https://github.com/akamai/boomerang/issues

Edit, I see that you already did: https://github.com/akamai/boomerang/issues/321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Navigation Timing** API / Specification comes in two versions:

- [Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) from 2012
- [Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/) from 2021

Level 1 is supported [by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/nav-timing)

Level 2 is [not yet supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=PerformanceNavigationTiming), e.g. Safari

Level 1 relies on JavaScripts Date object, which is imprecise and can lead to falsy timestamps, as you have observed.

Level 2 uses [High Resolution Time](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-3/) to solve exactly this problem and ensures monotonically increasing timestamps.

Boomerang is using Level 1, thats why you see corrupt timestamps.